# SAS Consecutive Date calculator ends after one consecutive date

Tags: date, sas

I have a SAS script in which I am attempting to find all of the ranges of consecutive dates in the column called shop_dttm.  Additionally, all of the other columns of data need to be the same for two observations to be counted as consecutive dates. However, currently, my program only gives me pairs of consecutive dates rather than consecutive date ranges of length greater than 2 days.

Code:

```
%let indata = WORK.OFFSELL_ZE;
%let location = city_cd;
%let class = shop_car_type_cd;
%let length = lor;
%let shop_dttm = datepart(shop_dttm);
%let chkdate = shop_dttm;
%let numconday = 0;
%let outdata = WORK.shop_date_range_ZE;


proc sort data = &indata nodupkey;
    by &location &class &length &chkdate;
run;

data = &indata;

data one;
    set &indata;
    by &location &class &length &chkdate;
    tempdate = lag(&chkdate);
    if (first.&location & first.&class & first.&length) then tempdate=.;
    retain cflag;
    if (first.&location & first.&class & first.&length) then cflag = 1;
    if &chkdate ne tempdate+1 then cflag = cflag +1;
run;

data two(keep = &location &class &length cflag consecutive);
    set one; 
    by &location &class &length cflag;
    retain consecutive;
    if first.cflag then consecutive = 0;
    consecutive = consecutive +1;
    if last.cflag and consecutive>=&numconday;
run;

data three;
    merge one two(in=a);
    by &location &class &length cflag;
    if a;
run;

proc sort data=three;
    by &location &class &length cflag &chkdate;
run;

data four;
    set three;
    by &location &class &length cflag &chkdate;
    retain firstdate;
    if first.cflag then firstdate = &chkdate;
    firstdate = datepart(firstdate);
    lastdate = datepart(lastdate);
    format lastdate firstdate mmddyy10.;
    lastdate = firstdate + consecutive;
    if last.cflag;

run;

proc sort data=four(drop=cflag &chkdate tempdate) out=&outdata;
    by &location &class &length firstdate;
run;

proc sql;
alter table &outdata
    add advance_days num label = 'advance_days' format = BEST.
    add range_length num label = 'range_length' format = BEST.
    modify arv_dt date format = mmddyy10.;
update &outdata
    SET advance_days = arv_dt - firstdate;
update &outdata
    SET range_length = consecutive;
alter table &outdata
    drop consecutive;

quit;
```

Data have:

```
city_cd      shop_car_type_cd         lor          arv_dt        shop_dttm
atl            bcar                     1          6/1/16          6/1/16
atl            bcar                     1          6/1/16          6/3/16
atl            bcar                     1          6/1/16          6/2/16
atl            ccar                     1          6/1/16          6/4/16
atl            bcar                     1          6/1/16          6/5/16
atl            bcar                     1          6/1/16          6/6/16
atl            bcar                     2          6/2/16          6/7/16
```

Data want:

```
 city_cd   shop_car_type_cd   lor    arv_dt    shop_start  shop_end  consec_days
    atl           bcar          1    6/1/16     6/1/16       6/3/16     3
    atl           bcar          1    6/1/16     6/5/16       6/6/16     2
    atl           bcar          2    6/2/15     6/7/16       6/7/16     0
    atl           ccar          1    6/1616     6/4/2016     6/4/16     0
```

Comment: Post more sample data and output, specifically what happens in non consecutive cases.

Comment: I think that my additions to the sample data and output are more encompassing now but let me know if there are any other cases you think I should include. I am really just looking for a loop that I am missing that will let this program calculate multiple consecutive days into a range rather than do them all individually and output them individually so the fix could be relatively simple I believe

Comment: Why isn't 6/1 to 6/6 counted as one row with 6 consecutive days?

Comment: because 6/4 is a ccar type not a bcar so the ranges are not consecutive since they are not referencing the same product

Comment: Are you familiar with the lag/dif function. Setting your BY variables properly and then using lag or dif to check difference should be relatively easy to identify consecutive groups.

Comment: I am not very familiar with those functions. That's why I am asking what I am missing that is preventing this program from working over longer consecutive date ranges. How could I implement this program using the lag/dif function @Reeza